# Connecting to Azure SQL using Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, firewall

I have a script that uses SQLAlchemy to connect to Azure SQL database.
I am running this script on Azure databricks, but every time the cluster starts I need to manually add the Databrick's IP address to the firewall of Azure SQL, so that the code can access the database.

Is there a way where whenever cluster starts the IP gets added to the SQL, so that I can create an automated pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve the goal, is to set an exception on Azure SQL firewall to allow Azure Services traffic.

[image]

A more secure way to achieve the same goal is associate the Databricks cluster to a VNET (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject)) and then whitelist the VNET on Azure SQL.

[image]